# Is it true that $e^{\sin(3.14)}e^{3.14} \le e^{\sin(3.15)}e^{3.15}$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, derivatives, exponential-function

I have to determine whether is it true that $$e^{\sin(3.14)}e^{3.14} \le e^{\sin(3.15)}e^{3.15}$$ and whether it is a equality. I even don't know how to begin with it...

Comment: Have you tried taking logs?

Comment: Show that : $\sin{(3.14)}+3.14\leq \sin{(3.15)}+3.15$ (and apply the exponential as it is monotonically increasing for $x\in\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Hint: Show that $x\rightarrow x + \sin x$ is an increasing function.

Comment: @gammatester but $((x + sin x)')(\pi) = 0$

Comment: Yes but that does not mean that the function is not increasing.It would be locally strictly decreasing, if you could find a derivative which is $< 0$. But $1+ \cos x \ge 0$.

Comment: @alex: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181269/prove-that-x-sin-x-is-strictly-increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can use the mean value theorem on $f(x)=\sin x$ so that $f(y)-f(x)=f'(\xi)(y-x)$ for some $x\le \xi\le y$ provided you can bound the derivative suitably.

Answer (score 0):

Since $exp$ is monotonically increasing, this reduces to
$$f(3.14) \le f(3.15)$$
where
$$f (x) = x + sin(x)$$
So

$$\begin{align}
f'(x) & = 1 + cos (x) \\
& \ge 0
\end{align}$$

So ...

Answer (score 0):

Let f(x)=x+sin(x), x = 3.14, y = pi, z = 3.15.
Then using the mean value theorem f(z) > f(y) > f(x),- in both cases ">", but not "≥".